# Formatting Embedded Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to insert a google spreadsheet to my website that can refresh when updated that does not contain the sheet name or title header from google.  I am able to get the spreadsheet linked but the formatting of the table is not what I would like.  Please help me prevent the tab and header from showing on my table.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a special tab which contains the output in the format you need to embed, however this will not solve the header problem. Best thing you can do is to create a special tab, without and name the tab just a dot  [example](http://astyle.home.xs4all.nl/beautyfarm2003/aanbieding_start.html#LASTMINUTE)